# Why does the parent element have additional space when child pseudo element set to display inline-block?

Tags: css

Example:
https://codepen.io/229075284/pen/aboQVXZ

```css
  .outer{
    background-color: pink;
}
.outer::after{
    content:'';
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
   /* display: table; */
}
.inner{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

When I set `display` of `outer::after` to `inline-block`,the outer will have some extra space marked as pink, even if set `font-size` and `line-height` to `0`. However, when I set `display` to `table`,the extra space disappears.

So I am wondering why the extra space appears?

Comment: font-size and line height should go to the parent element

Comment: and the overflow:hidden is changing the baseline of the element to be its bottom that's why you will also have this issue even if you have text inside. This will make it behave the same as image thus the first duplicate (the second one will allow to get more details about alignment in general)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codepen. It is a combination of both `display: inline-block` and `content: ""` on the `::after` pseudo element. You are basically telling the browser that right after the outer element you want to reserve an element's place in the DOM.

You could see that if you remove the `content: ""` although you are using inline-block the extra pseudo div after the `.outer` element would disappear. That is because although you stated a certain display mode you practically have no content in this element and the browser ignores your element because it has no fixed size in pixels and no actual content within it.

The reason `.outer` is growing is that its height is set to `auto` in default, if you would give it a fixed height in pixels it might not show the spare div.

Your question has nothing to do with `line-height` or `overflow'.

Me personally I prefer not to use pseudo-classes like `::after` and `::before` in production. I prefer using regular divs and have my code more readable and understandable by other developers, anyway I hope I helped out. Feel free to discuss further if you have more questions.

Comment: I'm already set `line-height` to `0` and set `overflow` to `hidden`, but it still exsit. And, when i remove `content` of `outer::after`, the pseudo element will disappear in DOM tree.Otherwise, i try to set `content` of `outer::after` to `url()`,the extra space still exsit.